# Apache VirtualHost error: Invalid host name

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, centos6

It used to be pretty simple for me to set up a VirtualHost to test a new php webapp, for this http.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /opt/webgrind/www
        ServerName webgrind
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /opt/opencart/www
        ServerName opencart
</VirtualHost>
```

I just needed to restart the service and access: `http://webgrind/` or `http://opencart/` (without changing anything in `/etc/hosts`)

But something changed in the server (CentOS 6) and now the `error.log` states:

```
[error] avahi_entry_group_add_service_strlst("opencart") failed: Invalid host name
[error] avahi_entry_group_add_service_strlst("webgrind") failed: Invalid host name
```

And when accessing `http://webgrind/` I get a page ofline error. Any ideas?

> Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
>   Server built:   Dec  8 2011 18:10:49

Comment: have you try to use fqdn in you server name when you are configuring apache virtualhosts?

Answer (score 5):

Since this question is the first that shows up when searching for "AH02415: [strict] Invalid host name", I will add an answer to document the time I wasted today because most of the virtual hosts in my development machine stopped working (e.g. shop_one.web).

I had Apache updated to version 2.4.16-18.1 and apparently `HttpProtocolOptions` now defaults to `Strict`, thus rejecting my local hostnames that have '_' (underscore) in them (and probably those of the OP).

I know they are not proper hostnames, but for local/personal use never hurt anybody, so I added the line:

```
HttpProtocolOptions Unsafe
```

to my default-server.conf and life is back to what it was before.
See also:

> https://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_24.html
>
> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340013/why-am-i-getting-400-bad-request/341306

Answer (score -1):

Configuring a virtualhost in apache does not make the name resolution service on the server know about it, so you would either have to update /etc/hosts, or do something like:

`curl -H 'Host: webgrind' 127.0.0.1`

to override the default behavior.